# Proof concerning Numerical Integration using Monte Carlo Methods

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, monte-carlo, integral

Im currently trying to proove that:

Let $ f:[0,1]^r\to [0,1]$ a contiunous function and $(X_{n,k})$ for $   n \in N, 0<=k<=r $. be independently and identically distributed random variables with a Uniform(0,1) distribution. Show that for $Z_n: Z_n= 1,$ if $X_{n,0}<= f(X_{n,1}, ... ,X_{n,r})$ and 0  elsewhere,  that 
$E(Z_n)$= $\int fd \lambda ^r $

A hint into the right direction would be nice. I have no idea how to do this.

The Integral $E(Z_n) $ is obviously the probability that $X_{n,0}<=f(X_{n,1}, ... ,X_{n,r})$ but I have no idea how to calculate this.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I have an Idea
$E(Z_n) = \int_{0}^1 Z_n(X_0(\omega),....,X_r(\omega)) d P ( \omega )= \int_0^1Z_n(x_0,...,x_r)d[X(P)] = \int_0^1...\int_0^1f(x_o,...,x_r)d \lambda(x_o)....d \lambda(x_r)=\int_0^1...\int_0^1\chi_{(f(x_1,...,x_r)>x_o)}d\lambda(x_1)...d\lambda(x_r) d (x_0) = \int_0^1 \lambda^r(f(x_1,...,x_r)>x_0)\lambda(x_0)=\int_0^1f(x_1,...,x_r)d \lambda ^r$

is this correct?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Yes. I dont want the full proof, just a hint into the right direction

Comment: Then please tell us where are you stuck and add `[self-study]` tag as described in https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: What has this to do with Monte Carlo methods?

Comment: How am I supposed to know that? My Prof said so xD

Comment: Why did you use this title? Tell some more about what your prof said, and what you understand by Monte Carlo methods, such that other people may understand your problem better.

Comment: The homework task is about numerical Monte Carlo Integration. So I thought it makes sense to write it into the title even though I dont really understand it yet. Is the title missleading?  If so I will remove it

Comment: as soon as I understand everything myself I will update the post. Only the title of the homework question said "Numerical Integration using Monte Carlo". So I unfortunately cannot provide more information about the problem yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $$E(Z_n) = \int_{X_1 \cdots X_n \in \left[ 0,1 \right] ^r} \left( \int_{X_0 \in \left[ 0,1 \right]} Z_n d X_0 \right) dX_1 \cdots dX_n $$

and start with finding out how you can rewrite:

$$\int_{X_0 \in \left[0,1\right]} Z_n(X_0,X_1 \cdots X_n) d X_0 $$